# can product url be in different language?

Tags: magento2, url

As I understand product title will be translated to product url like this

ex) product title : Asus Monitor -> url : http://yoursite/asus-monitor.html

my problem is that I have a lot of products from Korea that has Korean product name, and it seems Magento 2 doesn't accept foreign chars for product url.

ex) product title : Samsung 모니터 -> url : ***yoursite/samsung.html***
                     (모니터 = monitor)

see the problem here that it just cut off Korean part from the name..

is there way to let Magento 2 accept foreign chars for product urls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box, Magento does not support UTF-8 characters as URL keys. This has been discussed before, though, have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27767027/magento-does-not-support-using-unicode-characters-as-url-key) topic where two solutions are suggested.